# Top part of google places autocomplete is being hidden behind bottom of nav bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-places-api

I'm using places autocomplete in a text box inside a bootstrap nav bar, but it seems like the top part of the autocomplete results are being cut off or are hidden behind the bottom part of the nav bar. Here is a pic and the code.

**UPDATE - one thing I noticed is that if I remove 'navbar-fixed-top' from the nav element then then navbar increases its height and the autocomplete results aren't chopped off anymore. Why does this class shorten the hieght of the navbar?

[image]

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">



            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarSearchQuery" name="location">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

```js
 var navbarInput = document.getElementById('navbarSearchQuery');
 var navbarOptions = {
   types: ['geocode']
 };
 var navbarAutocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(navbarInput, navbarOptions);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at the z-index

Bootstrap's navbars z-index is 1000,  navbar-fixed 1030

The z-index from google maps autocomplete also is 1000

Comment: thanks. I'll use this. I didn't realize theyu were so high. I tried 1000, but it didn't change. Now I'm using like 2000.

Comment: I had the same issue.  Changed the z-index to 900 fro the navbar and it work perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the relevant CSS to change your Autocomplete dropdown here > [Style the Autocomplete and SearchBox widgets](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete).

Example: This will move the entire dropdown (not the input) lower.

```
.pac-container {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This was a useful answer and didn't deserve the down vote.